# Blowing up a projective surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups, singularity-theory, ade-classifications

Let $X$ be a smooth degree $d$ ($d>5$) surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$. We now blow up $X$ at a point, embed it in some projective space, and and consider a projection of it into $\mathbb{P}^3$. The question is does this resulting surface have only ADE singularities? If not when is it the case? What is the degree of the final surface?

Comment: The phrasing could use a little work.  Given that your blowup Y of X cannot be embedded in P^3 (the canonical bundle is of the wrong type) I assume you are asking for an embedding of Y in some projective space together with a projection from Y to P^3 which is birational onto its image and has only ADE singularities.  Is this correct? 

Comment: @Mustopa: Thank you. You are completely correct. 

Comment: If you do not fix the embedding of Y into a projective space, the degree can be almost anything (with fixed d).